# make dll of c++ in dev-C++

Tags: c++, dll, autohotkey

I've been attempting to compile dll of this c++ function for 2 days, unfortunately unsuccessfully. Watched about 8 videos on youtube and all the codes looked different in each video. Was confused with it.

All I want it to have is a DLL which I can call in my autohotkey script to make mouse or keyboard events (since ahks mouse&kb doesn't work on all types of window).

If you know how to make it in Dev-C++ or got any tips I'd be grateful, thanks.

```
POINT getCurrentPos(HWND hwnd)
{
    POINT cpos;
    GetCursorPos(&cpos);
    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &cpos);
    return(cpos);
}

void rightClick(HWND hWindow, POINT k)
{
    POINT currentPos = getCurrentPos(hWindow);
    DWORD coordinates = MAKELPARAM(k.x, k.y);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, MK_RBUTTON, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, MK_RBUTTON, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, coordinates);
    coordinates = MAKELPARAM(currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coordinates);
}

void leftClick(HWND hWindow, POINT k)
{
    POINT currentPos = getCurrentPos(hWindow);
    DWORD coordinates = MAKELPARAM(k.x, k.y);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, MK_LBUTTON, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, coordinates);
    coordinates = MAKELPARAM(currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coordinates);
}

void dragDrop(HWND hWindow, POINT from, POINT to)
{
    POINT currentPos = getCurrentPos(hWindow);
    DWORD coordinates = MAKELPARAM(from.x, from.y);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, coordinates);
    coordinates = MAKELPARAM(to.x, to.y);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, MK_LBUTTON, coordinates);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, coordinates);
    coordinates = MAKELPARAM(currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
    PostMessage(hWindow, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, coordinates);
}

void KeyUp(HWND hwnd, int vk_key)
{
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, vk_key, (MapVirtualKey(vk_key, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)) * 0x10000 + 0xC0000000 + 1);
}

void KeyDown(HWND hwnd, int vk_key)
{
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, vk_key, (MapVirtualKey(vk_key, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)) * 0x10000 + 1);
}

void KeyPress(HWND hwnd, int vk_key)
{
    KeyDown(hwnd, vk_key);
    KeyUp(hwnd, vk_key);
}
```

Comment: ***Watched about 8 videos on youtube and all the codes looked different in each video. Was confused with it.*** Remember that videos about how to code in `c++` are often wrong. Read the official documentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use dllexport, dllimport

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx